# Model hook loading with refreshModel

Tags: ember.js

My `Route` currently looks like:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    queryParams: {
        dateFrom: { refreshModel: true },
        dateTo: { refreshModel: true }
    },

    model(params) {
        return this.store.findRecord('foo', params.id, {
            adapterOptions: {
                filter: {
                    dateFrom: params.dateFrom,
                    dateTo: params.dateTo,
                }
            }
        });
    },
});
```

When the query param is changed on the route, the model hook is fired again. Is there a way I can tell if the model hook is in a loading state? I have tried `model.isLoading` in my template, but this doesn't seem to update when `refreshModel` is triggered.

I don't want to use loading substates, as I need a property I can pass into components.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this approach, but still, you can try it inside the route,

```
actions: {
        loading(transition, originRoute) {
            //if you want to set controller property, this.controller.set('isLoading',true); will do
            this.set('isLoading',true);          
            transition.promise.finally(() => {
               this.set('isLoading',false);                   
            });
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This only seems to fire when the route params changes, not the query params.

Comment: thats not true,please have a look at this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/136d8dab3af8c19c79cd4c4578fe476d?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C&route=%2F%3Fsearch%3Dk) .  if the model hook dont immediately resolve then loading event will be fired on that route. reference https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_the-code-loading-code-event

Comment: You are correct when the `model` hook is `Ember.RSVP.Promise` but doesn't seem to work for a `findRecord`

Comment: findRecord also return promise but I think this will return immediately what is avaliable in store and later on it will request the server to load it. so in your case it might be loaded quickly from store so that is the reason its not going for loading state..may be you can check with `reload:true` option to force waiting until server return the result `return this.get('store').findRecord('model-name', 1, {reload:true})`

Comment: This seems to be the case, I need to call `{reload:true}` in order for the model loading hook to be fired correctly. thanks