# Ember - Preload page Not triggering for slow model

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to add a preloading page for my slow model page. But my router not show the template for preload.

here is my structure of route:

http://localhost:4302/cs2i/purchase/purchaseDetails

```
this.route('cs2i', function() {

    this.route('purchase', function() {
      this.route('purchaseDetails', function(){
        this.route('loading'); //not loading I do have template
      });
      this.route('purchaseDetails-loading'); //not loading I do have template
    });
  });
```

what is the issue? how can i put a preloader to my route untill my data and template are rendered?

thanks in advance.

As well I do have a action with my 'purchase' page, which is triggeres even before data load.

```
actions: {

        loading : function( transition, originRoute ){

            console.log("loding done");//getting before data load

        },
```

Comment: I think you dont need to specify it in router.js for loading..this will automatically will pick and render if it exists

Comment: So just template is enough?

Comment: I have removed the route from router.js. But still the template is not picking up... any twiddle?

Comment: Created this twiddle for you https://ember-twiddle.com/5fce3666bfa02e024cfb2cc36d53d8b7?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C

Comment: @kumkanillam - it works fine. But apart from page load, there is multiple `ajax` request i have on each page. how can i handle those? using the same / new preloading stuff?

Comment: You can try this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/44370334/5771666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a loading action on your route overrides the default behavior (showing the template). You need to return `true` from your loading action if you want to show the loading template.

See: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_the-code-loading-code-event

Also note that if you're loading data in the `purchase` route's model hooks, the `purchase.loading` template/route will be loaded and not `purchase.purchaseDetails.loading` as described in your router configuration.

Comment: my data loads on "purchaseDetails" only.